# CodeSandbox editor has stopped auto completing the corresponding JSX closing tags?

Tags: autocomplete, tags, jsx, intellisense, codesandbox

CodeSandbox editor used to auto generate the corresponding close tag for the current tag.

For example:

```
<div> // THEN IT WOULD AUTO GENERATE THE </div> TAG
```

[image]

But don't know exactly when, it stopped doing that, and I have to write it manually. Is there a way to enable this autocomplete again?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the codesandbox.io go to:

**File -> Preferences -> Settings**

In the *Search Settings* box type `Javascript Autoclosing Tags`.

Enable that feature by checking the Checkbox.

Comment: You also have to turn Emmet back on - for autocompleting tag and component names.  Not sure when, or why, this was removed from the default behavior when it's the default behavior of just about every other editor.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting an updated answer since the UI has changed for codesandbox. I believe this answer is now slightly better:

- Press `cmd+,` (`ctrl+,` on a windows) with the editor focused (this opens the vscode settings)
- You should see a settings page like so:
  [image: image of vscode settings]
- In the Search Settings box type `Javascript Autoclosing Tags`
- Toggle the checkbox on

Answer (score 2):

In my case the auto completion works if a change the extension of the file to .jsx and if I start typing the tag without the <.

Comment: You may have to go into settings>User Settings>Extensions>Emmet and enable "Trigger Expansion On Tab." That was my problem. That's the only way I know how to use Emmet is by Tab.